# how can I get Twitter Bootstrap wells to be the same height as their outer div?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a Bootstrap grid to create a quad chart, and leveraging the CSS3 flexbox layout mode discussed [here](http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/) to make each column in the same row the same height. However, I want to use a Bootstrap well in each quad to highlight the "quad-ness" of the chart and I can't seem to figure out how to get the wells to fill all the space in the column divs.

```html
<div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="well">
            hello<br/>world<br/>how<br/>are<br/>you?
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="well">
            hi!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="well">
            hi!
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="well">
            hello<br/>world<br/>how<br/>are<br/>you?
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a playground [here](http://liveweave.com/iC4OhO) (be sure to go full screen on the result to see the quad chart).

I tried modifying the well class' CSS to set height to 100%, but that just seems to increase the height of the outer divs as well (example [here](http://liveweave.com/CBZDwL)).

Any ideas how I can get the wells to fill up the divs they're in without increasing the height of the divs?

**Edit #1**

To be clear, I'm not asking how to get all of the columns in a row the same height. The Flexbox solution using the `row-eq-height` class does that for me.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to make the Bootstrap `well` within a column div be the full height of the column div, regardless of how much content the `well` contains.

I've updated my two examples (linked above) to include border lines around the column divs to try and better articulate what I'm talking about.

Comment: There is a nice article on that: http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-columns-of-same-height

Comment: @Deka87 thanks for the article... I've seen it before but I think it's focused on getting all the column divs the same height. That's not my question here. I've edited my original post above to try and better reflect what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Looked like a duplicate. See my answer on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39551544/bootstrap-well-same-height

Answer (score 0):

Check this **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/kf3nb4sc/1/)**

```
 <div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-xs-6 "><div class="well">column 1</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 "><div class="well">column 2<br>this is<br>a much<br>taller<br>column<br>than the others</div></div>

      </div>
        <div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-xs-6 "><div class="well">column 1</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 "><div class="well">column 2<br>this is<br>a much<br>taller<br>column<br>than the others</div></div>

      </div>
```

Comment: thank you. However, I think this is what I was already doing. Please see the edits to my original question above where I tried clarifying my question.